# Android: display sentence from text file stored in res/raw folder

Tags: android, text-files

I am new to android and i Struck at this point.My text file contains wordings with number like 
1abcd efg hij klmn opqrs. 
2hdgh eydg ieuyhd gdhdgl. 
3hdgf dhgfhs fhghs dhghj. and so on. 
Now i need to display full sentence start with 1. please help me out from this problem.

Comment: you can use strings.xml to read text scripts.

Comment: thank you for replay i will try using  strings.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your text file in "Assets" folder of project and use following code to retrieve that file in java class

```
        try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("YOUR_TEXT_FILE.txt")));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        message=total.toString();
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After that you have that file in String message and you can retrieve string starting from "1" from that.

**EDIT**
TO RETRIEVE STRING STARTING WITH 1
use can use following code-

```
String newString;    
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
char c = message.charAt(i);
if(c=='1'){
          for (int j = i; j < message.length(); j++){
          if(c=='2'){
                    break;
                     }
          else{
              newString += message.charAt(j);
               }
               }
               break;
               }        
}
```

Now String newString will contain String starting with '1'.

Good Luck

Comment: working.., thank you for the replay. now i have my file data in String message. But how can i retrieve that string starting from 1.